# criar um loop no dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe

Eu tô trabalhando em uma análise de dados e gostaria de criar uma nova coluna. Cada linha dessa nova coluna vai ser a soma de todas as linhas de uma coluna já existente até aquele momento.

Por exemplo:
estou na linha 6 da coluna f (essa é a que vai ser criada) e quero somar as 5 primeiras linhas da coluna e (já existente) e colocar esse resultado na coluna f.

Pensei neste loop, mas como ainda estou aprendendo não funcionou:

```
for n in range(0, len(df['realized_pnl_usdt']) - 1):
    lista.insert(i, df['realized_pnl_usdt'])

    soma = sum(lista)

    lista2.insert(j, soma)

    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1

df = df.assign(realized_trade = lista2)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você deseja fazer uma soma acumulada até o momento mas com um lag, neste caso você pode utilizar a função cumsum junto com o shift do pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Criando um data frame de teste

```
coluna_f = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Coluna_F':coluna_f})
```

Aplicando o cumsum na coluna F e gerando uma nova coluna

```
df['somatorio'] = df['Coluna_F'].shift(1).cumsum().fillna(0)

display(df)
```

| Coluna_F | somatorio |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | 0.0 |
| 21 | 51.0 |
| 53 | 72.0 |
| 87 | 125.0 |
| 94 | 212.0 |
| 21 | 306.0 |
| 39 | 327.0 |
| 5 | 366.0 |
| 85 | 371.0 |
| 45 | 456.0 |